# Loop through radio buttons on a form using a construted variable name

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have several radio buttons on a form all grouped in 3's, and when they are clicked I need to run a JS function on them. In this function I loop through the radio buttons in the group of the button that was pressed (i.e. if the group was called 'abc_name' id use `for (var i = 0; i < form.abc_name.length; i++){  }`).

I'm wondering if there is a way to action a group of radio buttons in the same way using a constructed group name? For example if I passed 'xyz' to the function I'd need the code to be `for (var i = 0; i < form.xyz_name.length; i++){  }`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html).

```
function loopDeLoop (xyz) {
    var elems = form.elements[xyz + "_name"],
        len = elems.length,
        i;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        console.log(elems[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks, that is just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You should *really* be using `getElementsByName()` in both cases;

```
for (var els = document.getElementsByName(xyz + '_name'), i=0; i<els.length;i++) {
    // something on els[i]
}
```

Although the direct equivalent for what you've got would be:

```
for (var els = form.elements[xyz + "_name"];, i=0; i<els.length;i++) {
    // something on els[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a play shortly. What is the reasoning behind that suggestion though? I assume it's faster?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` property syntax:

```
function loop(s) {
   s += '_name';
   var inputs = form[s];

   for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
       ...
   }
}
```

This is necessary when the property key is a variable - `a.b` syntax only works if `b` is a "literal".